# Pulling data from php website that uses jQuery. No relevant source information

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, iframe

I have a tricky one, I am trying to scrape data from http://www.vafinancials.com/v5/plugins/quick_stats.php?id=25129.

I was able to do this for another website where I pulled the page source and parsed the source for the data I was looking for. However with this site I can't seem to find any way of scraping the relevant data.

So I am curious how would one scrape data on such a site where jQuery seems to be generating the result behind closed doors.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Which data do you want?

Comment: @intboolstring I am trying to get only the numeric values. I could careless about the names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Firebug or the integrated developer tools of your browser to see what's going on with the requests and responses of the page.

In your case there is an ajax call fetching the data:
[image: Firebug Parameter]

The response is XML:
[image: Firebug Response]

I would use this URL to fetch the data.

Comment: You say I should use "This URL" to fetch data. Which URL are you referring to? The XML one in the screenshot? Do you happen to have a direct link to that. I'm sure I can do it myself but just in case.

Comment: Yes, the one in the screenshot:
http://www.vafinancials.com/v5/plugins/app/x_quickstats.php?id=25129&key=7657

But you should figure out if the "key" parameter could change.

Comment: Awesome Christoph, let me give this a try! I would upvote this but I don't have 15 rank yet.